# Automatically load Wordpress page on server every XX hours

Tags: php, server-load

I have a page in my Wordpress site that calculates post popularity and updates several meta fields on the posts and calls a few functions as well. This page is set to "Private" so that only myself and other admins can see it. Is there a way to load this page automatically every 6, 12, or 24 hours?

I'd be satisfied with a plugin, but generally prefer to write my own PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [WP-Cron functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category%3aWP-Cron_Functions) to scheduled events. Note though that this is pseudo-cron- it requires someone (or a bot) visit your site for the events to execute.

To fire events more reliably, search for scheduling cron jobs (linux) or scheduled tasks (win). Depending on your hosting, you may have access to simple tools to schedule events, for example cPanel has a GUI for setting up cron jobs.